# Is there a way to do a .Where(function(x) x.id in [array])?

Tags: vb.net, filter, where-clause

I want to filter a list of entities that I am fetching from a database.

In fact, I ***should*** be getting only 1 entity back and I want to make sure its category is one of the allowed ones.

What's the best way to filter?

My first thought was to do something along the line of :

```
Dim allowedCat As List(Of Guid) = New List(Of Guid)
allowedCat.Add(Entites.Categories.Email)
allowedCat.Add(Entites.Categories.Mail)
allowedCat.Add(Entites.Categories.Fax)

Dim communications = communicationService.fetchCommunications(idComm)

resultatComm = communications.Resultat.Where(function(x) x.idCategorie in allowedCat)
```

Of course, it doesn't work and I'm having issue finding documentation on that "Where".

Comment: Note that a `HashSet(Of Guid)` would give better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB.Net doesn't have an `in` operator like that.

Instead, check `allowedCat.Contains(x.idCategoie)`.